# Heretic series playing order

Tags: heretic-series

I recently bought the Heretic and Hexen games on steam. I already played the original Heretic and I would like to know what is the suggested playing order of the Heretic and Hexen series based on the storyline?

Comment: Why the downvotes people? Can somebody explain?

Comment: I will admit, I had initially downvoted thinking "chronologically, obviously", but it turns out its not necissarily that simple. So I apologise, and have reversed my vote. That said, pattern shows that asking about downvotes has a better chance to just get you more downvotes. I dont agree with downvoting for that reason, but it's good to be aware that that can happen.

Comment: @Timelord64 will keep in mind thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most ideal order to play the games is the ordered chronology, as released by the developers. If at all available, you should also consider the expansion packs. Keep in mind that the expansion packs are not standalone; For the best experience, they should be installed prior to playing the base game.

They are as follows:

- Heretic

  - Expansion: Shadow of the Serpent Riders<sup>1</sup>
- Hexen: Beyond Heretic (commonly known as "Hexen")

  - Expansion: Deathknights of the Dark Citadel
- Hexen 2

  - Expansion: Portal of Praevus
- Heretic 2

#### Heretic vs Hexen

Hexen is still considered a sequel to Heretic. However, they are set in different realms. It is only with Heretic 2, the last released title, where the player is put back in the shoes of the main character from Heretic. That said, the first three titles make up what is called "The Serpent Riders Trilogy", and the Hexen set continue on from the overarching story of Heretic.

So ultimately, if you have a greater fondness for the main character out of Heretic than the overarching story concerning the Serpent Riders, you may have a more enjoyable experiencing jumping straight into Heretic 2.

<sub><sup>1</sup> Shadow of the Serpent Riders is considered an expansion, but is actually the retail release of the original Heretic. Originally, you could only purchase Heretic directly from the developer, and there was no retail release. When a retail release came out, it was titled "Shadow of the Serpent Riders", and included extra game content. Unless you have a really old version of the game, this is probably the version you are currently playing.</sub>

Comment: I played the original Heretic back in the 90s. It was a on a CD a bought with a some other games (Duke Nukem 2, Skyroads, Descent etc) so yeah I played the really old version :) but yeah I bought the whole collection on steam. So yeah. The problem is though that on steam it is missing heretic 2. So I guess I will follow the order you suggested until I find a way to obtain Heretic 2

Comment: @JohnDemetriou, it sounds like you may have had the shareware version, if it came with other titles on the disc (I had quite a few of these discs). If that is the case, you might find you were playing the first act, and your current version has 4 more. If not, the expansion added 2 acts, for a total 5 (for what I found online).

Comment: I bought this https://www.gog.com/en/game/heretic_hexen_collection But it doesn't have Heretic and Heretic 2. Is it complete? Also, is the Crystal Dome the ending of Heretic, shadow of the serpent riders? Because nothing happens after.